# Javascript counting sum of price * quantity returns NaN

Tags: javascript

I have a problem with my code.

```
$('input[name="pocet"]').each(function(){
                var $mnozstvo = parseInt($('this').val());
                var $id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(6));
                var $aktualnyProdukt = $('#' + $id);
                var $povodnaCena = parseFloat($aktualnyProdukt.data('price'));
                var $riadkoveZlavy = $aktualnyProdukt.find('div .vypocetPreZlavu');
                var $aktualnaCena = $povodnaCena;
                if($riadkoveZlavy.length > 0) {
                    $riadkoveZlavy.each(function() {
                        $mnozstvoNaZlavu = parseInt($(this).data('mnozstvo'));
                        $cenaPoZlave = parseFloat($(this).data('cena'));

                        if($mnozstvo >= $mnozstvoNaZlavu) {
                            $aktualnaCena = $cenaPoZlave;
                        }
                    });
                }

                if(isNaN($mnozstvo)) $mnozstvo = 0;
                total += $mnozstvo * $aktualnaCena;
});
```

However, after running this function, total returns NaN and I have no idea why. Could you help me?

HTML:
   http://jsfiddle.net/UL7Sr/

Comment: I hope those variable names will not be a huge problem for you, as they are in Slovak language.

Comment: It's a bit tricky :))..Make sure you're not using any string in the multiplication...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $povodnaCena = parseFloat($aktualnyProdukt.data('price'));

var $povodnaCena = parseFloat($aktualnyProdukt.attr('data-price'));
```

Replacing the first line with the second one solved my problem.

Answer (score 4):

`var $mnozstvo = parseInt($('this').val());` should actually be `var $mnozstvo = parseInt($(this).val());`

Additionally, make sure that `$aktualnaCena` is a number. You do this for `$mnozstvo`, but not for `$aktualnaCena`. Try:

```
if(isNaN($mnozstvo)) $mnozstvo = 0;
if(isNaN($aktualnaCena)) $aktualnaCena = 0;
total += $mnozstvo * $aktualnaCena;
```

Also, please don't prefix all your variables with a $. JavaScript is not PHP. The convention when using jQuery is that you do that for jQuery element variables to distinguish from other variables. If you use it for all your variables in that context, it is actually confusing.

Comment: Also, since $(this) is used several times, it would make sense to do it once and save it as a variable: `var elem = $(this)`. Each time you do `$(...)` you are forcing jQuery to create a new object.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I am new to jQuery so I do not understand everything just yet. However, there seems to be another mistake in the code, as this has not solved my issue.

Comment: @MarošGašparík, I updated my answer with something else you can try

Comment: I actually did that, but then it only returned 0, so there must be a mistake somewhere else. I added a link to JsFiddle with a few divs from my html code. Maybe a mistake is there, could you check that?

Comment: Your JsFiddle was not working, so I re-factored it and now it works see [http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/3NBGP/11/](http://jsfiddle.net/neelsg/3NBGP/11/). Not sure what is different though

Comment: it is just for you to have an idea of how my html code looks, the function is not supposed to work there